# Permission Problems in ubuntu 18 avoid wordpress plugins to run?

Tags: wordpress, php, ubuntu

i'm getting 2 main errors when i activate a wordpress plugin. It was working fine but just after changing some settings got 500 internal error. After debug I found these warnings like if there were a file it doesn't exists:

```
[19-May-2021 15:13:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(/home/submarin/public_html/wp- 
content/plugins/ilab-media-tools/ilab-media-tools.php): failed to open stream: No such file or 
directory in /home/submarin/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 388

[19-May-2021 15:13:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 
'/home/submarin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ilab-media-tools/ilab-media-tools.php' for inclusion 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/submarin/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 388

[19-May-2021 15:13:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos(): Empty needle in /home/submarin/public_html/wp- 
includes/plugin.php on line 694

[19-May-2021 15:13:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/submarin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ilab- 
media-tools/ilab-media-tools.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/submarin/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6109

[19-May-2021 15:13:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos(): Empty needle in /home/submarin/public_html/wp- 
includes/plugin.php on line 694
```

And then it finds the file:

```
[19-May-2021 15:13:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 
'MediaCloud\Plugin\Tools\ToolsManager' not found in /home/submarin/public_html/wp- 
content/plugins/ilab-media-tools/ilab-media-tools.php:198
```

Plugin is https://wordpress.org/plugins/ilab-media-tools/
Running in Wordpress 5.6.4
Ubuntu 18 and webmin/virtualmin Panel.

Media Cloud support says it seems to be a permission problem on my side but i ran out of ideas on what to do. I have done the basics: Deleting the plugin several times and re-installed, cleaned the database and wordpress cache. Still no luck so if there is something i'm missing to configure on my server please help me with your insights.
Thanks

Comment: does /home/submarin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ilab- 
media-tools/ilab-media-tools.php exist?

Comment: Are the files which are being complained about readable and executable by the web server? Did you upload them via FTP or the Wordpress backend? (the latter will likely resolve permissions issues - but only if the files dont already exist with another owner.)

Comment: Yes, file exists. 
I tried both: upload by ftp and from wordpress. Same result. Whenever i go to activate the plugin the 500 internal error is there with those 2 errors.